# If __metaclass__ is a class attribute, how does it control the generation of the class?

Tags: python, python-2.x, metaclass

We know that when generating a class in Python2, if there is a **metaclass** attribute, it will be generated by the metaclass referenced by the attribute. Bug when the class is not generated, it should have no attribute, how does it control the generation of the class?

Comment: What do you mean, "control the generation of"?

Answer (score 3):

Because the body of the class definition statement is evaluated *before* the creation of the class object.

So indeed, the class doesn't have that attribute, *the class doesn't even exist yet*. But the class definition statement *has* been evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

The Python implementation itself first gathers the names defined in the namespace of the `class` statement, then generates a call to the metaclass with those names passed as a mapping argument to the metaclass. That is, something like

```
class Foo:
    x = 3
```

is used to generate something equivalent to

```
Foo = type('Foo', (), {'x': 3})
```

as `type` is the default metaclass.

When the name `__metaclass__` is encountered in the namespace, the implementation uses the value as the metaclass instead of `type`.

```
class Foo:
    __metaclass__ = Bar
```

becomes (roughly)

```
Foo = Bar('Foo', (), {'__metaclass__': Bar}).
```

---

(I am purposely ignoring the lack of an explicit base class for `Foo`. I don't fully understand how a seemingly old-style class with a specified `__metaclass__` differs from a "pure" old-style class or another new-style class, but any differences don't seem relevant to the question at hand.)